# Redirect with .htaccess to exact URL provided

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I want to redirect from old sites url to new one. Lets say `example.com/en/some/stuff/foo/bar` needs to be redirected to `example.com/some/stuff`.

Here is what I have at he moment:

```
Redirect 301 /en/some/stuff/foo/bar/ /some/stuff/
```

The problem is that I end up being redirected here `example.com/some/stuff/foo/bar`, but I need as I defined inside .htaccess `example.com/some/stuff`.

How to redirect properly to exact URL I have provided without anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule with regex in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/(some/stuff)/.+ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser to avoid old cache.